# Sitecore User Group Quebec #4 - June 13, 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

**Date/Time (local):** June 13, 2018 at 5:30 PM

**Date/Time (UTC):** June 13, 2018 at 9:30 PM

**Location:** Coveo office, 3175 Chemin des Quatre-Bourgeois, Suite 200, G1W 2K7 · Québec, QC

**Registration is mandatory:** https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Quebec/events/251218924/

**Who to contact for information:** Jean-François L'Heureux

**Description:**

This is the fourth meetup of Sitecore User Group Quebec. We have confirmed the main presentation. **We would like to have one or two more. Contact us if you are interested in presenting, even just for a few minutes.**

MAIN PRESENTATION

**From Forms to Riches**

by Kamruz Jaman and Mike Reynolds

> WFFM is dead. Long live Forms. One of the most popular Sitecore
>   modules has finally been given a modern overhaul. Moving from a mature
>   module presents both great opportunity but also new challenges trying
>   to replicate well established business processes. What the new
>   Experience Forms means to you and how to integrate with Marketing
>   Automation and EXM to maximise your marketing and personalisation
>   opportunities.

**Presenters:**

**Kamruz Jaman** - Sitecore MVP & Sitecore Consultant - @Konabos

> I have over ten years development experience building dynamically
>   driven web based and desktop applications. I have experience of the
>   full project lifecycle from feasibility, analysis, development and
>   team management to hand-over including preparation of specifications,
>   budgets and project plans as well as other formal documentation and
>   client liaison during the project. I am highly skilled in front end
>   design and browser manipulation using advanced HTML, CSS and
>   Javacript/jQuery techniques.
>
> I am experienced in working with various development methodologies
>   including waterfall and Agile, making use of SCRUM, storyboarding and
>   sprint techniques. I have made extensive use of Web 2.0 technologies
>   to develop highly responsive websites using Sitecore CMS and ASP.Net
>   using C#.

**Mike Reynolds** - Sitecore Architect / Sitecore MVP

> Michael Reynolds, a Sitecore MVP with almost nine years of Sitecore
>   architecture and development experience, is an independent consultant
>   with a proven track record of pushing the envelope of the Sitecore
>   platform to deliver best-of-breed solutions for clients.
>
> A well-known thought leader in the Sitecore community, Reynolds was
>   recognized as a Sitecore Technology MVP in 2014, 2015 and 2016 for his
>   community contributions.

**Agenda:**

- 17:30 - Beer, drinks, and networking
- 18:00 - Presentations
- 20:00 - End of the event (might be earlier)

The presentations will be in English and we will try to record them. The meetup will not be streamed.

Please RSVP only if you plan to come in person to help us plan the drinks quantity.

Looking forward to meeting you

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion began 16 hours ago